# Transforming in a shorter way

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, syntax

Is there an elegant way to shorten this part of code:

```
adhesiveCoord = array(adhesiveCoord)
adhesiveCoord = adhesiveCoord[:,0]
adhesiveCoord = list(map(int, adhesiveCoord))
```

Using Python 3.6 and Numpy

Thanks for help.

Comment: What is the type of `adhesiveCoord` beforehand?

Comment: from the beginning it was an array, just transformed it to a numpy array

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this is a great place for [list-comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk).

You can do something like this:

```
adhesiveCoord = [int(x[0]) for x in adhesiveCoord]
```

Which, if I understand correctly in your case, should work to take the first column of each of the rows and cast it as an int into a list. =)

---

Just another small note, it's **not** standard to do this. (again, if I understand what the "array" is here)

```
from numpy import array

adhesiveCoord = array(adhesiveCoord)
```

But much more standard to do

```
import numpy as np
adhesiveCoord = np.array(adhesiveCoord)
```

One reason for this is so everyone can see what kind of array it is. That way, we can all immediately understand how it is supposed to behave

Comment: thanks again for your edit! thats a good advice with import ... as ... :)

Comment: If that worked for you, maybe you can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)  =)

Answer (score 1):

```
np.array(adhesiveCoord)[:,0].astype(int)
```

or maybe

```
np.array(adhesiveCoord, dtype=int)
```

depending on what's in the first column.

`np.array` can convert all valid strings into integers without a python loop or map.

```
In [213]: alist = [['a','1'],['b','2'],['c','3']]
In [214]: np.array(alist)
Out[214]: 
array([['a', '1'],
       ['b', '2'],
       ['c', '3']], dtype='<U1')
In [215]: np.array(alist)[:,1]
Out[215]: array(['1', '2', '3'], dtype='<U1')
In [216]: np.array(alist)[:,1].astype(int)
Out[216]: array([1, 2, 3])
```